# How to define as Save As Function in Python

Tags: python

hello I have below code like this, I would like to do save as same name but add a Tag New to same file name so save it as new_TBM. Any help is appreciated.

```
import sys
from tableaudocumentapi import Workbook

sourceWB = Workbook('C:\\Users\\rmakkena\\Music\\TBM.twb')

sourceWB.datasources[0].connections[0].server = "MY-NEW-SERVER"
sourceWB.datasources[0].connections[0].dbname = "NEW-DATABASE"
sourceWB.datasources[0].connections[0].username = "rithesh"

sourceWB.save_as()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to do a bit of processing on your (*basename* part of the) filename. For that, we use [[Python]: os.path — Common pathname manipulations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path). How it's done:

- Split the file name into:

  - *dirname* (directory tree path: *C:\Users\rmakkena\Music*) and
  - *basename* (plain file name: *TBM.twb*)
- Add the "*new_*" prefix to the *basename*
- Rejoin the 2 parts together (*C:\Users\rmakkena\Music\new_TBM.twb*)

The (slightly modified) code (check [[GitHub]: document-api-python/tableaudocumentapi/workbook.py](https://github.com/tableau/document-api-python/blob/master/tableaudocumentapi/workbook.py): `def save_as(self, new_filename):`):

```
import sys
import os
from tableaudocumentapi import Workbook

file_name = "C:\\Users\\rmakkena\\Music\\TBM.twb"
new_tag = "new_"

sourceWB = Workbook(file_name)

sourceWB.datasources[0].connections[0].server = "MY-NEW-SERVER"
sourceWB.datasources[0].connections[0].dbname = "NEW-DATABASE"
sourceWB.datasources[0].connections[0].username = "rithesh"

sourceWB.save_as(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file_name), new_tag + os.path.basename(file_name)))
```